# How do I get rid of the ruby version on my prompt through zsh?

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh, zshrc

I have zsh and think that I need to go to the profile through ~/.zshrc and then add export PS1=”$“ to get rid of the ruby version, but I'm not sure which export to replace?

[image]

Comment: try sudo nano ~/.zshrc. You need to choose a program to open the file with.

Comment: One supposes removing `${rvm-prompt}` would do the trick.

Comment: @Ravenous Why would he need super user permissions to change a file in his home directory? The OP did not mention any permission issues. Also, if you surround code snippets with backticks, they will be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `${rvm-prompt}`...

Also, for further easy customization take a look at - [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) - A delightful community-driven framework for managing your zsh configuration.

Answer (score 0):

as I am using `yadr` and `prezto` I had to open the file `~/.yadr/zsh/prezto/modules/ruby/functions/ruby-info` and comment this block, putting a blank to the `version` variable:

```bash
# if (( $+commands[rvm-prompt] )); then
#   version="$(rvm-prompt)"
# elif (( $+commands[rbenv] )); then
#   version="$(rbenv version-name)"
# elif (( $+commands[ruby] )); then
#   version="${${$(ruby --version)[(w)1,(w)2]}/ /-}"
# fi
version=""
```